# Is $\mathcal P_1(X)$ a necessary condition for the Kantorovich-Rubinstein Duality?

Tags: duality-theorems, optimal-transport

In many books, such as Villni's Optimal Tranport: Old and New, the Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality is written with the condition that $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal P_1(X)$. That is:
$$
\int_X |x|d\mu < +\infty \quad , \quad \int_X |x|d\nu < +\infty
$$

But, in some Lecture Notes that I found (and using Theorems and Propositions from Santambrogio's book), the Kantorovich-Rubinstein theorem is stated for $\mu,\nu \mathcal P(X)$, hence, without the need of the existence of a first moment. My question is then, is such condition indeed necessary?

Comment: The first moment condition is automatically fulfilled in the case where $X$ is compact. My guess is that the lecture notes you are looking at make such an assumption.

Comment: Hmm -- actually I see your other, related question. I will try and give a better answer later, but briefly: the W1 distance only "makes sense" when the first moment is finite, in the sense that the distance between any two measures in $\mathcal{P}_1(X)$ is finite provided they both have first moments.

Comment: In particular, one expects that the "inf" in the KR duality will be infinite otherwise, so the KR duality may still hold vacuously if the first moment condition is dropped, but it is no longer interesting.